# How to make a search bar in XPages?

Tags: search, xpages

I have an XPages database ready but I want to make a search page/bar to search through my database and display the linked information. As I am a beginner in XPAGES I would appreciate a step by step guidance:) or if you know any website with guidance i would appreciate any help:)

Answer (score 3):

An instruction to implement a search function can be found here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Tutorial-Introduction-to-XPages-Exercise-9

Other sites of interest:
[Learning xPages](http://www.qtzar.com/blogs/qtzar.nsf/htdocs/LearningXPages.htm)
[xPages wiki](http://www.xpageswiki.com/)
[xPages Info](http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Home.xsp)
[xPages Blog](http://xpagesblog.com/)
[xPages 101](http://xpages101.net/)
[notes in 9](http://www.notesin9.com/)
[xPages cheat sheet](http://www.xpagescheatsheet.com/)
[xPages TV](http://xpages.tv/)
[Domino Designer wiki](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf)
[Lotus Notebook](http://www.lotusnotebook.com/)
[Open NTF](http://openntf.org/Internal/home.nsf)
[Planet Lotus](http://planetlotus.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Use extlib.openntf.org - The application layout control has ready to use searchbar entries